# Python very slow random sampling over big list

Tags: python, performance, random, range

I'm expecting very slow performance with the algorithm below.
I've a very large (1.000.000+) list containing large strings.

ie: `id_list = ['MYSUPERLARGEID:1123:123123', 'MYSUPERLARGEID:1123:134534389', 'MYSUPERLARGEID:1123:12763']...`

`num_reads` is the max number of elements to random choose from this list.
The idea is to randomly choose one of the string ids in `id_list` until `num_reads` is reached and to add (I say add, and not append because I don't care on `random_id_list` order) them into `random_id_list` which is empty at the beginning.

I can't repeat same id so I remove it from the original list after being randonly chosen. I suspect this is what is doing the script to go real slow.. maybe I'm wrong and it's another part of this loop the responsible of slow behavior.

```
for x in xrange(0, num_reads):
    id_index, id_string = random.choice(list(enumerate(id_list)))
    random_id_list.append(id_string)
    del read_id_list[id_index]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) to produce a sample of N elements with no repeats:

```
random_id_list = random.sample(read_id_list, num_reads)
```

Removing elements from the middle of a large list is indeed slow, as everything beyond that index has to be moved up a step.

This does not, of course, remove elements from the original list anymore, so *repeated* `random.sample()` calls can still give you samples with elements that have been picked before. If you need to produce samples repeatedly until your list is exhausted, then *shuffle once* and from there on out take consecutive slices of `k` elements from the shuffled list:

```
def random_samples(k):
    random.shuffle(id_list)
    for i in range(0, len(id_list), k):
        yield id_list[i : i + k]
```

then use this to produce your samples; either in a loop or with `next()`:

```
sample_gen = random_samples(num_reads)
random_id_list = next(sample_gen)
# some point later
another_random_id_list = next(sample_gen)
```

Because the list is shuffled entirely randomly, the slices produced this way are also all valid random samples.

Comment: Amazing. I didn't know very much about random sampling in Python. You just made my day. Thank you sir !

Comment: For my problem It's enough with one random sampling. But it's always good to know how to produce multiple random samples without repeating elements.

Answer (score 0):

The "hard" way, instead of just shuffling the list, is to evaluate each element of your list in order, and selecting the item with a probability that relies on both the number of items you still need to choose and the number of items left to choose from. This is useful if you don't have the entire list presented to you at once (a so-called on-line algorithm).

Let's say you need to select `k` of `N` items. That means each item has a `k/N` probability of being chosen, if you can consider all items at once. However, if you accept the first item, then you only need to select `k-1` items from `N-1` remaining items. If you reject it, you still need `k` items from `N-1` remaining items. So the algorithm would look like

```
N = len(id_list)
k = 10  # For example
choices = []
for i in id_list:
    if random.randint(1,N) <= k:
        choices.append(i)
        k -= 1
    N -= 1
```

Initially, the first item is chosen with the expected probability of `k/N`. As you go through your list, `N` steadily decreases, while `k` decreases as you actually accept items. Note that each item, overall, still has a `p = k/N` chance of being chosen. As an example, consider the second item in the list. Let `pi` be the probability that you choose the `i`th element in the list. `p1` is obviously `k/N`, given the starting values of `k` and `N`. Consider `p2` for example.

```
p2 = p1 * (k-1) / (N-1) + (1-p1) * k / (N-1)
   = (p1*k - p1 + k - k*p1) / (N-1)
   = (k - p1)/(N-1)
   = (k - k/N)/(N-1)
   = k/(N-1) - k/(N*(N-1)
   = (k*N - k)/(N*(N-1))
   = k/N
```

Similar (but longer) analysis holds for `p3`, `p4`, etc.